# How to install packages from yaml file in Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I would like to have one YAML file that could serve to both create virtual environments and (most importantly) as a base for installing packages by conda into the global env. I am trying:

```
conda install --file ENV.yaml
```

But it is not working since conda expects `pip`-like format of the requirements. What command should I execute to install packages from my YAML file globally?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You want the `conda-env` command instead, specifically

```
conda env update -n my_env --file ENV.yaml
```

Read the `conda env update --help` for details.

If you wish to install this in the **base** env, then you would use

```
conda env update -n base --file ENV.yaml
```

Note that the **base** env isn't technically "global", but rather just the default env as well as where the `conda` Python package lives. All envs are isolated unless you are either [using the `--stack` flag during activation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation) to override the isolation or have - [contra recommended practice](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell) - manually manipulated `PATH` to include an env.

Comment: This does not work, I get:  
  
CondaEnvException: Unable to determine environment

Please re-run this command with one of the following options:

* Provide an environment name via --name or -n
* Re-run this command inside an activated conda environment.

Comment: I don't think you understood me. I want to install packages GLOBALLY. Instead of writing conda install X; conda install Y; conda install Z I just want to provide one file with specifications

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please update our answer with "--name base" and a link to explanation that the general conda environment is called base (so that I can accept it)? This would well serve for further generations.

Comment: @maciek I updated it, but I'll also caution that your **base** env is where Conda lives and the less you manipulate it the more stable it will be. I would especially avoid installing anything with `pip` in there.

Comment: One observation: the output from conda is a bit weird and doesn't actually tell you what it is installing so it can be a bit confusing because that is what I would expect.

Comment: @salotz yeah, the `conda-env` tool is a bit underdeveloped compared to the main tool. For instance, it also doesn't give you a chance to inspect the proposed transactions and choose to accept or reject them.

Answer (score 22):

If your conda env is already activated, use:

```
conda env update --file environment.yml
```

Or update a specific environment without activating it:

```
conda env update --name envname --file environment.yml
```

Comment: I encourage users get in the habit of always explicitly specifying the environment (`-n,--name` argument). Especially with the `conda env` commands, which do not prompt for review of changes.

Comment: conda env update --prefix /path/to/envname --file environment.yml 

I found this useful for environments installed in predefined paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gui tool for anaconda, you can basically do this by simple steps.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]